# Get a filtered Dictionary from a Dictionary using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary of type (string, string) which is a list of groups and their IDs. I need the 2nd dictionary which should not have five groups (which I know). Can anyone help me in framing the select in LinQ which I can use to create this sub dictionary?

Comment: Show some code please. We have no context with which to help you.

Comment: 3 answers.. apparently I'm the only one who can't make sense of your question. I apologise... I think?

Answer (score 1):

```
var myDic = new Dictionary<string,string>();
myDic.Add("1","One");
myDic.Add("2","Two");
myDic.Add("3","Three");
myDic.Add("4","Four");
//myDic.Dump();

var exclusions = new []{"2","3"};
var newDict = myDic.Where(x=> !exclusions.Contains(x.Key))
     .ToDictionary(x=> x.Key, x=> x.Value);
//newDict.Dump();
```

Comment: Ha! A LINQPad freak! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Found my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should to the trick:

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDic;

...

var badGroups = new[] { "badGroup1", "badGroup2", ... };

var my2ndDic = myDic
    .Where(e => !badGroups.Contains(e.Key))
    .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e.Value);
```

I suppose what you missed was the [.ToDictionary()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var groups = new List<string>();
        // Fill your groups
        var yourDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        //fill your dict.
        var filteredDict = yourDict.Where(a => !groups.Contains(a.Key)).ToDictionary(k=>k.Key,v=>v.Value);
```